# web scraping with puppeteer does not find the CSS tag

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

im starting to learn web scraping in javascript with puppeteer. I found a video that I liked that showcases puppeteer and I'm trying to scrape the same information as the video([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pixfH6yyqZk&t=1699s&ab_channel=DevTips)). the page has changed a little from the video so I used what I think are the correct tags.

the problem comes when I try to find the `"h3"` tag. the tag exists in the DOM but my code refuses to acknowledge its existence but works "fine" when looking for the `"h2"` tag.

what I want to know is why my code does not retrieve it.

web page: https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner?utm_source=marketingplatform.google.com&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=marketingplatform.google.com%2Fabout%2Fpartners%2F

```
// normal things to launch it
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async() => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   const url = "https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner?utm_source=marketingplatform.google.com&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=marketingplatform.google.com%2Fabout%2Fpartners%2F";
   
   await page.goto(url);

   // here comes the problem

   //                                                  this doesn't work    v
   const h3 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("h3").textContent);
   console.log(h3); //the error is because it tries to get the text content of null meaning it didn't found "h3"

   //                                                  this DOES work      v
   const h2 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("h2").textContent);
   console.log(h2);
   

   //await browser.close();
})();
```

i know that `"h3"` exists. I will appreciate it if you explain a little of what happens so I can learn more
thx.

Comment: try use `await page.waitForSelector('h3')` before assign (or inside `evalute` and make that `async` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h3 header not exist on page, we need wait it by `waitForSelector`:

```
// normal things to launch it
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async() => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   const url = "https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner?utm_source=marketingplatform.google.com&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=marketingplatform.google.com%2Fabout%2Fpartners%2F";
   
   await page.goto(url);

   await page.waitForSelector('h3')
   const h3 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("h3").textContent);
   console.log(h3);
   const h2 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("h2").textContent);
   console.log(h2);
   
   await browser.close(); // don't forget close it.
})();
```

output is:

```
Viden
 Find your perfect match.
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input. one last question... is there a command so that it waits until the whole page loads, so I can search for multiple things without using waitForSelector for each thing?